# Webcam Renaming

Tags: webcam, streaming, devices

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and I've got a dual webcam setup for Zoom.

They're both Logitech c615 cameras and the fact that the system is giving them the same default name is confusing.

I'd like to change them to something like CamA and CamB.

I've got System Profiler up and running, but it appears to be read only.